# Java Regex: matches(pattern, value) returns true but group() fails to match

Tags: java, regex

I have an odd problem with a regular expression in Java. I tested my Regex and my value [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html) and it works. It says there are 3 groups (correct) the match for the first group (not group zero!) is SSS, the match for group 2 is BB and the match for group 3 is 0000.  But my code below fails and I am quite at a loss why...

```
String pattern = "([^-]*)-([\\D]*)([\\d]*)";
String value = "SSS-BB0000";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(value);
//group() is equivalent to group(0) - it fails to match though
matcher.group();
```

Here is a screenshot from the matching result of the above website:
[image]

I'd be really grateful if anyone could point out the mistake I am making... On an additional note: Strangely enough, if I execute the following code true is returned which implies a match should be possible...

```
//returns true
Pattern.matches(pattern, value);
```

Comment: when you say it fails to match, do you mean you get an empty string back from `group()`, or is there an exception thrown?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to call `find()` before `group()`:

```
String pattern = "([^-]*)-([\\D]*)([\\d]*)"; 
String value = "SSS-BB0000";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(value); 
if (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group()); // SSS-BB0000
  System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); // SSS-BB0000
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // SSS
  System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); // BB
  System.out.println(matcher.group(3)); // 0000
}
```

When you invoke `matcher(value)`, you are merely creating a `Matcher` object that will be able to match your `value`. In order to actually scan the input, you need to use `find()` or `lookingAt()`:

#### References:

- [`Matcher#find()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29)

Comment: `find()` works because it skips `matcher.group(0)`, which is the whole `Matcher`.

Comment: It does not skip anything. Trying to execute `group()` before calling actually scanning the input -- using `find` or `lookingAt` --- will result in an `IlegalStateException`.

Comment: @JG, you are correct.  I misunderstood the question.  I was under the impression that the asker was just trying to get the first group, and that they were instead getting the whole string (group 0).

Comment: Oh my, thank you a lot :O! This is embarassing - I guess its rather obvious that I just got started on the whole regex subject - thank you very much :)!

Comment: I am spending my hours for this detail. This is terrible to provide this kind of usage and not explaining clearly. Thanks for the clear, one sentence statement.

Comment: FYI in addition to Matcher#find() and Matcher#lookingAt(), which don't match the entire region, you can also use Matcher#matches(), which requires that the whole region matches the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Was calling `matcher.group(1)` **WITHOUT** checking `matcher.find()`. Adding if check for `matcher.find()` solved the problem.