# Java - Regex/Pattern/Matcher - How do I identify and store all mismatches?

Tags: java, regex, csv, pattern-matching

Code snippet from a CSV File validator:
I have created the [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html), and it identifies if there's a match or not.
Next I want to identify if there is not a match, which field is not matching and causing the error.

What's the best way of doing this?

```
Pattern bodyPattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{11}),([A-Z0-9]{7}),([0-9]{7,8}),([0-9]{1}\\W[0-9]{2}E\\W[0-9]{2}),([0-9]{7,8}),([A-Z]{5}),([A-Z]{8,25}),(\\d+\\.\\d{0,2}),([0-9]{3})");

Matcher matcher = bodyPattern.matcher(line);

if(matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("SUCCESS: Body validation was successful");
} else {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Body validation failed in line " + lineNumber);
}
```

Output currently looks like this.
I want to be able to say fails at token number x but unsure how to do this.

> Line # 1, Token #1, Token: 20171006003
>   Line # 1, Token #2, Token: OUTWARD
>   Line # 1, Token #3, Token: 1000004
>   Line # 1, Token #4, Token: 2.00E+36
>   Line # 1, Token #5, Token: 1000005
>   Line # 1, Token #6, Token: FALSE
>   Line # 1, Token #7, Token: ACCEPTED
>   Line # 1, Token #8, Token: 400
>   Line # 1, Token #9, Token: 826
>   ERROR: Body validation failed in line 1
>   ERROR: Body validation failed in token number

Comment: So basically you wish to say which field is invalid in the csv?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Regex: matches(pattern, value) returns true but group() fails to match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033082/java-regex-matchespattern-value-returns-true-but-group-fails-to-match)

Comment: In that answer to that dupe question is basically what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

using java api, it seems there is no way to retrieve information after a failed match indeed in the general case regexes can backtrack and final state may not be useful but in that particular case it may be interesting to inspect Matcher through reflection:

```
// to make Matcher.groups field accessible
Field matcherGroups = Matcher.class.getDeclaredField( "groups" );
matcherGroups.setAccessible( true );

Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "^(a+)(b+)(c+)$" );
Matcher m = p.matcher( "aaabbcccc" );
m.find();

int[] groups = (int[])matcherGroups.get( m );
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( groups ) );

m = p.matcher( "aaab bcccc" );
m.find();

groups = (int[])matcherGroups.get( m );
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( groups ) );
```

output is

```
[0, 9, 0, 3, 3, 5, 5, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
[0, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
```

the first match succeeded and group regions are set

- 0:9 : group 0 : `aaabbcccc`
- 0:3 : group 1 : `aaa`
- 3:5 : group 2 : `bb`
- 5:9 : group 3 : `cccc`

the second match failed only group 0 contains the region of subsequence which matched

- 0:4 : for `aaab`  in `aaab bcccc`

For your particular case, you may define a Regexp for each field and to split the String with `,`.